# Infinite scroll with django not loading next pages upon scrolling down

Tags: django, pagination, django-templates, django-views, infinite-scroll

**Intro:** I am using this https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/03/13/how-to-create-infinite-scroll-with-django.html to add infinite scroll with django. Just in case anyone wants the detailed code its on Github.It is a very simple code

https://github.com/sibtc/simple-infinite-scroll

**The issue:** I have a total of 8 posts. I can see 3 posts in my homepage. Ideally as soon as I scroll down more 3 posts should show. I know the views are fine as the print statement in the view works and it is showing only 3 posts. Usually if there is a problem loading infinite scroll the `More` link should show. But that is not showing as well. Where am I going wrong

> **What I have done so far:**

- In my static folder. I made a folder called `js` and added 3 files in it

  - `infinite.min.js`, `jquery-3.1.1.min.js`, `jquery.waypoints.min.js`
  - I copied the code exactly from the github in my files

**Below is my view:**

```
class Homepage(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home.html'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(Homepage, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    all_posts = Post.objects.all()
    page = self.request.GET.get('page', 1)
    paginator = Paginator(all_posts, 3)
    try:
        posts = paginator.page(page)
        print(posts)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        posts = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    context['post_list'] = posts
    return context
```

**Below is my base.html:**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>{% block title %} Infinite Scroll{% endblock %}</title>
        <meta name="description" content="{% block metadescription %}{% endblock %}">
        {% load staticfiles %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'style.css' %}">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default".....> #navbar   

      <div class="container">
         <div>
             {% block body %}
             {% endblock %}
         </div>
             {% include 'footer.html' %}
       </div>


      <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js' %}"></script>
      <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.waypoints.min.js' %}"></script>
      <script src="{% static 'js/infinite.min.js' %}"></script>
      {% block javascript %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

**Below I have my home.html:**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block javascript %}
  <script>
    var infinite = new Waypoint.Infinite({
      element: $('.infinite-container')[0],
      onBeforePageLoad: function () {
        $('.loading').show();
      },
      onAfterPageLoad: function ($items) {
        $('.loading').hide();
      }
    });
  </script>
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<div class="col-md-6" style="background-color:white;">
    <div class="infinite-container">
        {% for post in post_list %}
            <div class="infinite-item">
                <div class="list-group"....>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
   </div>

   <div class="loading" style="display: none;">
       Loading...
   </div>

   {% if post_list.has_next %} #I also tried {% if page_obj.hasnext %}
      <a class="infinite-more-link" href="?page={{ post_list.next_page_number }}">More</a>
   {% endif %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Where am I going wrong. I have checked and rechecked the code again and again

[image]

Comment: is there any error show in browser console?

Comment: @ShafikurRahmanShaon `<div class="infinite-container"> ` is not showing in the inspector the console is blank

Comment: @ShafikurRahmanShaon should I use `console.log` on something to see if I get a error. Its been a while I worked on Javascript and Jquery sorry for any stupid question

Comment: I will work on it. Wait for a moment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `home.html` place following block after body block

```
{% block javascript %}
  <script>
    var infinite = new Waypoint.Infinite({
      element: $('.infinite-container')[0],
      onBeforePageLoad: function () {
        $('.loading').show();
      },
      onAfterPageLoad: function ($items) {
        $('.loading').hide();
      }
    });
  </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: One of the error messages_____________This site appears to use a scroll-linked positioning effect. This may not work well with asynchronous panning; see https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Mozilla/Performance/ScrollLinkedEffects for further details and to join the discussion on related tools and features!

Comment: but the github code does infinite scrolling without any errors

Comment: remove this `<script src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js' %}"></script>`

Comment: Nope that did not do it

Comment: may be you make something mistake. I test same git repo and works fine for me. Do you check your jquery, waypoint and infinite js. again?

Comment: The git repository works for me too. Yes checked that 2-3 times making the deleting the file and `cntrl  A` , `cntrl  C` , `cntrl V` I am sure I have those files correct

Comment: can you add a screenshot of browser console after reloading the page?

Comment: Added the image. Sorry Print screen button was not working for some reason on my ubuntu virtual machine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185805/discussion-between-shafikur-rahman-shaon-and-samirtendulkar).

Comment: This is 404 that means the URL that plugin tries to load does not exist.
Make sure URL that is being passed to infinite-scroll is correct.
Also make sure page  key is correct.

Answer (score 0):

view.py

Class

```
class ArticlesView(ListView):
    model = Article
    paginate_by = 5
    context_object_name = 'articles'
    template_name = 'blog/articles.html'
```

Def

```
def home(request):
    numbers_list = range(1, 1000)
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    paginator = Paginator(numbers_list, 20)
    try:
        numbers = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        numbers = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        numbers = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return render(request, 'blog/home.html', {'numbers': numbers})
```